# Add 2 hours to calculated Date and Time field

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I have calculated Date and Time field with Formula

```
=NOW()
```

is possible to add 2hours using formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can add days to that  by coding =NOW()+2  That gives you 2 days from now. It expects the number to be days. To add hours, do

```
=NOW()+(2/24)
```

Or you can change the 2/24 to 1/12, but I usually leave it /24 so it's easier for me to understand.